# Browser Back Button Cause Dynamic Content to Load

Tags: infinite-scroll, back-button-control

I am using Wordpress, with a plugin called "Visual Portfolio" It has a feature that allows some of the content to load, then when you scroll down, it loads more portfolio thumbnail content, like an infinite scroll feature for pagination.

The problem is, this makes it so if content is loaded dynamically, when they go to a portfolio item, then press back, the content is not loaded in the same way, and they can't easily go to another portfolio item, without scrolling down again.

Is there any way to solve this, so when they press back, it loads the page the way it was when they were their before?

Thank you for your attention on this